# POST to PHP without page refresh?

Tags: php, jquery, html, sql, ajax

**UPDATED - PLEASE HELP!!! IT DOES NOT LEAVE THE PAGE BUT IT DOES NOT POST TO THE SQL SERVER ANYMORE**

I have followed multiple online forum posts to try and get the answer to this, but I keep getting the same thing. I just want to post without refreshing the page. My code is below, please let me know where I am going wrong.

Below is the AJAX post portion (in file: edit_project_new.php):

```
      $(document).ready(function() {
 $("#proj_submit").click(function(event) {
        var pname=document.getElementById('pname').value;
        var p_start_date=document.getElementById('p_start_date').value;
        var con_start_date=document.getElementById('con_start_date').value;
        var con_end_date=document.getElementById('con_end_date').value;
        var p_end_date=document.getElementById('p_end_date').value;
        var IDF_room_ready=document.getElementById('IDF_room_ready').value;
        var AV_install_date=document.getElementById('AV_install_date').value;
        var Occupancy_date=document.getElementById('Occupancy_date').value;
        var PID=document.getElementById('PID').value;


        event.preventDefault();

            $.ajax({
            type:"POST",
            url: "edit_project_new.php?action=update_project",
            data: { 
                name1: PID, name8: p_start_date, name9: con_start_date,
                name10: con_end_date, name11: p_end_date, 
                name12: IDF_room_ready,
                name13: AV_install_date, name14: Occupancy_date },
            success: function() {
                alert("Updated");
            }


    });
});
```

});

Below is the HTML table and form (in file: functions_new.php):

```
  <form method="post" action="#">
                <input type="hidden" id="PID" name="PID" value="">
 ...
        <input type="button" id="proj_submit" class="ui blue submit button right floated" value="Update">
            </form></div>
```

Below is the SQL query portion (in file: functions_new.php):

```
if ((isset($_GET['action'])) AND ($_GET['action'] == "update_project")) {
    $pname= $_POST['pname'];
    $PID=$_POST['PID'];
    $p_start_date=date('Y/m/d', strtotime($_POST['p_start_date']));
    $con_start_date=date('Y/m/d', strtotime($_POST['con_start_date']));
    $con_end_date=date('Y/m/d', strtotime($_POST['con_end_date']));
    $p_end_date=date('Y/m/d', strtotime($_POST['p_end_date']));
    $IDF_room_ready=date('Y/m/d', strtotime($_POST['IDF_room_ready']));
    $AV_install_date=date('Y/m/d', strtotime($_POST['AV_install_date']));
    $Occupancy_date=date('Y/m/d', strtotime($_POST['Occupancy_date']));

    $sql2 = str_replace("'1969/12/31'","NULL","UPDATE Project SET p_start_date='$p_start_date', con_start_date='$con_start_date',con_end_date='$con_end_date',p_end_date='$p_end_date',AV_install_date='$AV_install_date',IDF_room_ready='$IDF_room_ready',Occupancy_date='$Occupancy_date' WHERE PID='$PID'");

    if (mysql_query($sql2)) {
        echo "Project record updated.";
    } else {
        echo "Error: " . $sql2 . "<br>" . mysql_error($link);
    }
}
```

Whenever I post, it will load a new page with just the echo "Project record updated." I feel like I'm very close but I am doing a little something wrong, so if someone could lead me in the right direction, I would greatly appreciate it.

Comment: try event.preventDefault at the start of click function

Comment: You didn't prevent the original form submissions from going ahead, so you START doing an ajax request, but also do the normal form submission.

Comment: How do I fix that?

Comment: For a start, you are attaching an event to the element with an id of 'submit', but there is no such element.

Comment: Hello Progrock, I changed that to proj_submit

Answer (score 1):

With [event.preventDefault()](https://api.jquery.com/event.preventdefault/) the default action of the click event will not be triggered.

Your form action tag can be removed and move the `action=update_project` to the [jQuery.ajax()](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/).

**JavaScript**:

```
$('#submit').click(function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();

    // your javasacript code

    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'functions_new.php',
        data: {
            name1: PID,
            name8: p_start_date,
            name9: con_start_date,
            name10: con_end_date,
            name11: p_end_date,
            name12: IDF_room_ready,
            name13: AV_install_date,
            name14: Occupancy_date,
            action: 'update_project'
        },
        success: function() {
            alert('Updated');
        }
    });
});
```

Note that now `action` will be a POST parameter.

**PHP**:

```
if (isset($_POST['action']) && $_POST['action'] == 'update_project') {
    // your php code
}
```

Comment: try to explain it .

Comment: Thank you for the response. That unfortunately still doesn't work for me, I have tried that.

Comment: Tried with event as well, still nothing :(

Comment: @MikeValentino your form action should look like this: `action="#"`

Comment: Okay, now we're onto something. But how do I call the SQL request?

Comment: Hi Yosvel, this still doesn't work :/ I get the alert but it appears to not be finding the $_POST=='update_project' properly, because it doesn't save to the database

Answer (score 1):

Change input `type=submit` to `type=button` to avoid the submit behavior of the button.

```
<input type="button" id="proj_submit" class="ui blue submit button right floated" value="Update">
```

Id of button above is `proj_submit` and here  `$("#submit").click(function()` you are using another button `id=submit` which probably has the `type=submit` attribute

Comment: Thank you for the response. I added this change and still have the same issue.

Comment: There's no way to submit the form with input type button unless you explicitly try to

Comment: So should I change button back to submit?

Comment: No. Change  `$("#submit").click(function()` to `$("#proj_submit").click(function()` or change the input type of submit button to `button`

Comment: I made those changes. Still the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

Did you miss the action parameters ?

```
    $.ajax({
    type:"POST",
    url: "functions_new.php",
    data: { 
        name1: PID, name8: p_start_date, name9: con_start_date,
        name10: con_end_date, name11: p_end_date, 
        name12: IDF_room_ready,
        name13: AV_install_date, name14: Occupancy_date,
        action: 'update_project'
    },

    success: function() {
        alert("Updated");
    }
```

and change in the php file :

```
if ((isset($_POST['action'])) AND ($_POST['action'] == "update_project")) {
```

and using `event.preventDefault();` is a good practice

Comment: I have made those changes. When I press the update button, it goes no where. Should the action in the form be "#"?

Comment: Yes let me show you what I've changed. I feel like it's all over the place lol.

Comment: You put the parameters action in the url, change what i write in my answer because its not the same code ;)

Answer (score 0):

You can preventDefault or use a link instead of submit button.

**1st Solution : PreventDefault :**

```
$( "#form-id" ).on( "submit", function( event ) {
  event.preventDefault();
  data = $( this ).serialize() ); //earn time with serialize()
  //your ajax code
});
```

**2nd Solution : if, like me, you don't love PreventDefault**

```
<span onclick="submitForm();">Submit</span>
...
function submitForm(){
   //your code
}
```

Comment: Hello, thank you for the response, but the preventDefault just doesn't fix the problem for me, I have added it to my code earlier.

Comment: If you prefer you can use an other html tag (2nd Solution).
I put the ".serialize()" on my response because I found it very useful

Answer (score 0):

```
    $( "form" ).on( "submit", function(e) {
     e.preventDefault();
    data = $(this).serialize();
     $.ajax({
        type:"POST",
        url: "functions_new.php",
        data:data,
        success: function() {
            alert("Updated");
        }
});
});
```

then the action can also added as hidden field

```
    <form method="post" action="#">
                <input type="hidden" id="PID" name="PID" value="">
          <input type="hidden" id="action" name="action" value="update_project">
 ...
        <input type="button" id="proj_submit" class="ui blue submit button right floated" value="Update">
            </form></div>
```

then next function_new.php page

```
  if ((isset($_POST['action'])) AND ($_POST['action'] == "update_project")) {
}
```

Comment: Besides this, everything else is okay as I posted above?